# gdb: break when a particular object is altered

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I have an object defined in c++ with a pointer to it used in various functions and files throughout the project.  I am having an issue with the data being updated, so I want to debug it to see what is happening.  Ideally, I want to break every time the object is accessed.  however, `watch` requires a specific memory address.  So, for example, if I have:

```
class data{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

then gdb will only break when `a` is altered, since the pointer to data is pointed at `a`, but not when `b` is altered.

Is there a way to break whenever the entire range of memory covered by the `data` class is altered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to break whenever the entire range of memory covered by the data class is altered?

Perhaps.

GDB hardware watchpoints use special debug registers in hardware, and there is usually a limit on how such registers work. On `x86`, you can set up to 4 word-sized hardware watch points, so for example you gave you *can* set watchpoints on `&data->a` and `&data->b`, and that will "cover" entire memory of the `data`.

I am guessing that your actual `data` has many more members though, and so 4 word-sized watch points will not suffice.

If you are on platform which has Valgrind support, and if your program can execute under Valgrind, then you can use Valgrind's built-in [gdbserver](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver) to set watchpoints on *arbitrary* regions of memory.

Update:

> I looked through the page you linked to and couldn't find what I was looking for

I am not sure what you were looking for. Here is a sample session showing how it works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(char *p)
{
  *p = 'a';
}

typedef struct {
  char buf[1024];
} data;

int main()
{
  data *d = calloc(1, sizeof(data));
  foo(d->buf + 999);
}

gcc -g main.c

valgrind --vgdb-error=0 ./a.out
...
==10345== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==10345==   /path/to/gdb ./a.out
==10345== and then give GDB the following command
==10345==   target remote | vgdb --pid=10345
```

... Valgrind now waits for debugger to attach.

In another window:

```
gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4
...
(gdb) target remote | vgdb --pid=10345
relaying data between gdb and process 10345
[Switching to Thread 10345]
0x0000000004000af0 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40053d: file main.c, line 14.
(gdb) c

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:14
14        data *d = calloc(1, sizeof(data));
(gdb) n
15        foo(d->buf + 999);
(gdb) watch *d
Hardware watchpoint 2: *d
```

Note that a "hardware" watchpoint has been set on *entire* `*d`.
It's a hardware watchpoint only in the sense that Valgrind is the hardware.

```
(gdb) p d.buf[999]
$1 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) c
Hardware watchpoint 2: *d

Old value = {buf = '\000' <repeats 1023 times>}
New value = {buf = '\000' <repeats 999 times>, "a", '\000' <repeats 23 times>}
foo (p=0x51b6457 "a") at main.c:6
6       }
(gdb) q
```

Voila: the debugger stopped when 999th element was modified, proving that the watchpoint "covered" the entire structure.

Comment: Thanks.  can you provide more information on valgrind?  I looked through the page you linked to and couldn't find what I was looking for