# Debug session freezes when trying to watch an array

Tags: c++, ide, gdb, anjuta, codelite

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I have used so far anjuta and codelite as IDE's for C++ school projects.
However, with both of them I have encountered one problem:
After starting the debugger, everything works fine till I try to add an array at watches' section. It does not display anything and when I try to continue debugging it freezes and I have to stop the debug session. I have to mention that watching variables works well.

Thank you,

LE: Actually, the debug function freezes only in case of large arrays...it may be a bug of codelite then. Any opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to mention that watching variables works well.

When you set the watchpoint on a variable, GDB probably says `Hardware watchpoint N` (but your IDE may be hiding that message).

When you set a watchpoint on anything larger than 8 bytes on x86 processor, GDB can not set a hardware watchpoint (because x86 hardware doesn't support such watchpoints). GDB sets a software watchpoint instead. Software watchpoints are implemented as follows:

1. single-step the program
2. did values change? No -> go to step 1. Yes: stop.

Software watchpoints are *really* slow. If you watch your system with `top`, you'll likely discover that GDB is consuming 100% CPU.

If you *really* need to watch an entire array, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321112/50617) shows how that can be done with valgrind.

Comment: Modern hardware supports watching max of 16 bytes, not word.

Comment: It really consumes 100% CPU, it takes about one minute going to the next instruction. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Dani Citation needed. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register, the maximum size for a watchpoint is 8 bytes; I've updated the answer.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: From that page: "enable the four address breakpoint conditions",  "each breakpoint ... specifies whether they watch ... one (00b), two (01b), eight (10b) or four (11b) bytes". Actually its 32 bytes, I didn't know the eight ones existed.

Comment: @Dani It's *bytes*, not words.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: 4 drs * 8 bytes = 32 bytes

Comment: @Dani A *single* GDB hardware watchpoint can watch up to 8 bytes. I don't believe GDB will set 2 `DR`s if you ask it to watch 16 bytes, but I could be wrong.